# What does Continuum Companion stand for?

Tags: grammar

Could anybody please explain to me what **Continuum Companion** means in the following title?

> The Continuum Companion to Systemic Functional Linguistics

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A **companion** is a useful reference on a subject, here "systemic functional linguistics."  It's published by **Continuum** International Publishing Group Ltd.